# RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "dist/esm/index.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup, gomuks

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "maxifinalnum",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "react component library",
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs"
  },
  "author": "maxxicov",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "keywords": [
    "tutorial",
    "button",
    "test"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.38",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.5",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^4.5.2",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^6.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/maxicov"
  }
}
```

This is my rollup configuration

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.js",
    external: ["react-dom"],
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    input: "dist/esm/index.js",
    output: [{ file: "dist/esm/index.js", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [resolve(), commonjs()],
  },
];
```

## when i try to do npm run rollup i get this error dist/esm/index.js → dist/esm/index.js...

[!] RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "dist/esm/index.js".
at Object.error (C:\Users\Desktop\final-test-lib\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:279:30)
at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (C:\Users\Desktop\final-test-lib\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19031:32)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
i am not using typescript in this sample code i only use plain reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Error indicates that the entry point specified in your Rollup configuration does not exist or is not correctly specified. In your case, it seems like there might be a few issues in your Rollup configuration that need addressing:

1. **Duplicate `input` Field**: You have two `input` fields in your Rollup configuration. Rollup expects a single entry point for each configuration object. If you need to bundle multiple entry points, you should define multiple configuration objects or use the @rollup/plugin-multi-entry.
2. **Incorrect Entry Point**: You've set the `input` to `"dist/esm/index.js"`. This should typically be the source entry file, not the destination. For a typical React project, this might be something like `"src/index.js"`.
3. **Destination as Entry Point**: You are using your build destination (`dist/esm/index.js`) as an entry point, which is incorrect. The entry point should be the source file that Rollup will use to start the bundling process.

You can try like this:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.js", // Adjusted to the correct entry point
    external: ["react-dom"],
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [resolve(), commonjs()],
  },
];
```